# Laptop upgrade possibilities. How and why (or why not)?

Tags: laptop, upgrade, computer-building, asus-laptop

I own an **Asus K45VM** that comes equipped (on-board) with an **Intel i7 3610QM Processor** (Turbos at 3.2GHz) and an **NVDIA GeForce GT 630M**  (2gb VRAM).

I'm already going to upgrade from an HD to SSD and from 8 to 16GB RAM. If I were to remove the useless DVD Rewriter the case has quite a lot of space, about **10x10x1cm** (len/wid/hei).

As a note I would like to add that the computer can run Witcher 3 on minimum settings for 5 minutes before overheating forces the laptop to cut down on performance so more cooling would be nice.

At any rate my questions are:

1. Is there any chance I can use the "empty" space for something useful? Another cooler if nothing else.
2. Are there any other upgrade possibilities that don't involve purchasing a new laptop?
3. (I know this one is a loong shot) Is there any chance of upgrading the on-board video card (as that is the main limiting factor imo)?

*I hope you can help me and thank you for your time!*

Comment: You cannot upgrade the video card in a laptop without changing the main board (motherboard) and generally laptop main boards are specifically designed for the laptop in question with the casing etc. designed around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can usually use the "empty" space for another SSD or hard drive - you get caddies to make this easyish.  (Your system looks to be supported here)

1a.  You can clean out your CPU cooler, or, if its dying, [look at replacing it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EBJI6TC).    Also looking at putting it on a [cooling fan/pad/mat thingy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NNMB3KS).

2. Very few upgrades internally are possible without a lot of risk and knowledge of resoldering that very few people have, and its probably not worthwhile.   If your battery is internal and aging, you can possibly swap that out.
3. Not unless you can unsolder the chips.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop can't support the upper limit of the video card you have there is no chance of it support and upgraded video card.  The laptops power supply would melt/break under the load of an upgrade card, if you could fit one in.  This is why it is not allowed.

However, a bit of research turned up external graphics cards for laptops.  I don't know if it is compatible or not, but you might be able to find a compatible version.

https://www.pcworld.com/article/2984716/laptop-computers/how-to-transform-your-laptop-into-a-gaming-powerhouse-with-an-external-graphics-card.html

I went and found, what I think is your laptops motherboard.

[image: wifi slot]
I found a description of the wifi card which states **PCIE half size Mini-Card**.  If this is truly a pci-e x1 slot then if you cut a hole in your case and got and adapter card that could plug into it to adapt it to x16 then maybe it would work, but still be faster than integrated but slower than a real x16 slot.

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-an-external-GPU-on-a-laptop-via-the-USB-3-0-port

TLDR Yes, but bandwidth and latency mean you won't get the best performance.  However, it will probably be faster than internal graphics.

[https://www.amazon.com/PCI-Half-Full-Mini-Adapter/dp/B01DEKQXP8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DEKQXP8)
[image]

Then something like this:
[https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812186323&cm_re=x1_to_x16-*-12-186-323-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812186323&cm_re=x1_to_x16-_-12-186-323-_-Product)

[image]

**You will need an external pc power supply to power all these extra parts.**

Even better is this:
https://youtu.be/bP_8EYQ-2RA

Found the homepage here: http://expgdc.net/

https://www.banggood.com/EXP-GDC-Laptop-External-PCI-E-Graphics-Card-p-934367.html
[image]

Comment: The Beast is probably the best/most well tested alternative here.